# iOS Provisioning Profile error

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am currently having some problems regarding provisioning profiles on the dev centre. In the past, I have been able to successfully create and deploy apps on internal app stores and on multiple devices. I have never run into trouble when trying to sign my apps. However, since the last update on the dev-portal, I have not been able to create new provisioning profiles - which is becoming a big problem.

I have successfully created an app id, com.xx.USApp and created a certificate for it: com.xx.USApp just as I did for all my other apps in the past. However, when I go to "Provisioning Profiles", I am unable to create a profile for any App ID (not even for the previous apps). When I try, I am able to select an App ID, then on the next screen, this message pops up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbCxt.png

It is telling me to create a certificate, which I have already done - as can been seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVwal.png

I have even tried to make additional ones through the links they have provided me, however whenever I go back to the Provisioning tab, the same message occurs. In the past, I was taken to this dialog: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPFPZ.png which then gave me a list of all my certificate files. I am wondering if this is a bug in their update and how I would go about resolving this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Good grief, they've completely changed everything! They got rid of the "portal" and put something else in its place. I had no idea. What a mess.

Comment: I know, this is just ridiculous... I am still having a LOT of trouble trying to create a provisioning profile. I can't even find their number anywhere... What have they done!

Comment: Usually you don't even need to go to the site, you can just request one from within Xcode. That may be only for team profiles though, I forget.

Comment: To distribute in-house apps with a distribution profile, you have to go within the site - as far as I know. For developer profiles, yes you can do it through Xcode as long as you do not need push services I believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with their servers when trying to create provisioning profiles. They have since fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has decided to move the place where you setup provisioning profiles to the member center.  That could be the problem.  Not sure why they moved it.  Try adding it from the new member center.