# Cannot edit provisioning profile under new Apple web interface

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

I have to update a Apple Provisioning Profile to add a new UDID, and when I logged into my Apple dev account it looks like Apple have just changed parts of their dev site.

I was able to add the new UDID without any issue, however when I try to update my Provisioning Profile by:

> Provisioning Profiles --> Development --> Select Profile --> click
> "Edit" --> add new device to the profile

The "Generate" button doesn't change from disabled state to clickable state. Even after changing all changeable fields (profile name, included certificates, devices), the "Generate" button still refuses to be enabled.

Below is the screenshot of the issue, you can see that "Generate" is in a disabled state:
[image: Screenshot of the screen at issue]

What I need to know is how to update Provisioning Profile, is the problem with me editing it wrong, or is it because of some bugs with the new interface.

**Edit 1**
Looks like it isn't browser specific. The situation is the same on Win7 Chrome and on OSX Safari (older & newer version). However, I did find that a large part of the site doesn't work on Win7 IE9, I click on a number of buttons and nothing happens.

Comment: i'he just checked this and it the generate button is enable even if i dont make any changes.may be you wont have permission to edit the profile.

Comment: People all over the site are having trouble with these new changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884464/ios-provisioning-profile-error

Comment: @wasim The account used to log in is the owner account, and is the only account we use to create/modify/delete certificate & profiles. Needless to say, it worked for us without issues in the past, before the site UI change.

Comment: @matt yeah, looks like another 'bug' created because of the changes. His issue is a different one though.

Comment: @Kai I experimented with new interface and its working. Trying deselecting and selecting certificate again and check, it worked in my case and generate button is enabled.

Comment: @Jennis I have done that already, selecting/deselecting all certificates/devices, selecting/deselecting some certificates/devices, changing app ID, changing profile name... none of them worked. I think it's not an across-the-board failure, but where it's working for some and not working for others.

Comment: @Kai, I've had issues with their new UI as well, although different. What if you tried the unorthodox method of enabling the button using firebug? Maybe it would work.

Comment: @RaduLucaciu My issue is resolved perfectly with Nicolas's answer below, maybe you can try it out as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that their new interface **doesn't accept any more underscore ("_") character** in the provisioning profile name.

When I renamed my provisioning profile name without any underscore in it, the generate button did become available again.

Comment: That's exactly what cause the problem for me. It all works after removing underscores from my profile name. Thanks!

Comment: My problem as well, fail Apple

Comment: Wow, this is ridiculous.  I want the last hour of my life back - Apple Fail++.

Answer (score 2):

Good news : The issue has been fixed by Apple.
We checked today and we were able to push the generate button even if the provisioning profile containes the underscore ("_") character .